# How do I make a Mario-like character movement with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I'm making a game with SpriteKit and I'm having trouble getting my characters movement to be similar to that of Super Mario.

I want to make him move sideways depending on which direction is touched and when the user lets go I want him to stop.

Is there a way that someone could help me write the necessary code?

This is my GameScene.swift file:

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

let character = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "character"))
var move = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    //world
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)

    //background
    var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    background.size.height = self.frame.size.height
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(background)


    //character
    character.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.6, self.frame.size.height * 0.6)
    character.setScale(0.015)
    character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(character.size.width / 2))
    character.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.addChild(character)


    //platform 1
    var platformTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
    var platform = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture)
    platform.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.6, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    platform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform.size)
    platform.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform.setScale(0.25)
    self.addChild(platform)

    //platform 2
    var platformTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
    var platform2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture2)
    platform2.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.4, self.frame.size.height * 0.3)
    platform2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform2.size)
    platform2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform2.setScale(0.25)
    self.addChild(platform2)


    //platform main
    var platformTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "platform")
    var platform3 = SKSpriteNode(texture: platformTexture2)
    platform3.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame) + platform3.size.height / 3)
    platform3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: platform3.size)
    platform3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    platform3.setScale(1)
    platform3.size.width = platform3.size.width * CGFloat(2.0)
    self.addChild(platform3)


}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
   var charPos = character.position
    /* Called when a touch begins */
   for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    //Hold finger at upper area to move character constantly to the right.
    if location == charPos{
        character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 20))
    }
    else {

    }
    if location.y > 400{
        //moving allowed, force is applied in update method. read the docs about applyImpulse and applyForce methods and the differences between those two.
        move = true

    }else{

        if location.x < CGRectGetMidX(self.frame){
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -10, dy: 0))
        } else if location.x > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame){
            character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 10, dy: 0))
                        }
    }

}

}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

}
}



 func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mario used a fairly simple character movement system - you will have problems mimicking it with a fully fledged physics system like you get with SpriteKit.

Mario was a tile-based game, and I imagine he had an `X`, `Y position` and an `xVelocity` and a `yVelocity`. Each runloop his velocity was calculated and his position updated. This is why you could change direction mid-air (your controller changed his velocity).

You will be fighting with a physics engine to mirror this, and you definitely don't want to be controlling a character by applying impulses: They resolve over time (as they slow down) and you can't control that.

Answer (score 1):

```
// :Ask Question Disable continuous movement and one movement per keyboard tapped or continuous movement when keyboard is held
// Swift-Mario Game: I need help to disable continuous movement, and I want one movement per keyboard tapped and continuous movement when keyboard is Held.


func run(direction: String) {

    if direction == "right" {

        let rightAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([rightTexture1, rightTexture2, rightTexture3, rightTexture4], timePerFrame: 0.08)
        let rightAnimationContinuous = SKAction.repeatActionForever(rightAnimation)

        let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(10, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
        let moveRightForEver = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveRight)

        hero.runAction(SKAction.group([rightAnimationContinuous, moveRightForEver]), withKey: "runningRight")

    } else if direction == "left" {

        let leftAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([leftTexture1, leftTexture2, leftTexture3, leftTexture4], timePerFrame: 0.08)
        let leftAnimationContinuous = SKAction.repeatActionForever(leftAnimation)

        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-10, y: 0, duration: 0.1)
        let moveLeftForEver = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft)

        hero.runAction(SKAction.group([leftAnimationContinuous, moveLeftForEver]), withKey: "runningLeft")
    }

    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(runningsound), withKey: "runsound") 
}

func stop(direction: String) {

    if direction == "right" {

        hero.removeAllActions()
        hero.texture = rightTextureStill

    } else if direction == "left" {

        hero.removeAllActions()
        hero.texture = leftTextureStill
    }

    self.removeActionForKey("runsound")
```